# How do I find record older than 90 days from a DATETIME field in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a field called `lastlogin` in my MySQL database. It holds `DATETIME` in this format: `2014-04-02 11:03:23`

What is the query to call to get all records older than 90 day from today?

Comment: Questions asking for code must show a minimal understanding and demonstrate attempted effort.

Comment: It would be helpful to read over the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Stop giving him a hard time and just write his query already, jerks!  What are you even paid for?

Comment: I am not sure why this question got so many negative points when similar questions get 100s of upvotes. Amazingly, it was never even edited.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting records older than a month/30 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27476325/deleting-records-older-than-a-month-30-days)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do it as so:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE lastLogin < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 90 DAY);
```