# Deleting records older than a month/30 days

Tags: php, mysql

I have data stored in mysql database. I am trying to delete all records that are greater than 30 days. All records have a field that specify a `created_date` of the record. The format of the `created_date` is `Mon, 08 Dec 2014 00:33:13 -0500`. When running the delete query, all record are deleted. Even records that are not older than 30 days. I am not sure if it is due to how the date is formatted in the `created_date` field. How can  I delete records older than 30 days?

```
try {
     $days = strtotime('1 month');
     $delete = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM archive WHERE created_date > :days");
            return $delete->execute(array('days' => $days));
        }catch (Exception $e) {
                      echo "Failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
```

Table schema

```
+------------+-----------+-----+---------------+---------------------------------+
| First Name | Last Name | Age | Date of Birth |           created_date          |
+------------+-----------+-----+---------------+---------------------------------+
| Lionel     | Messi     |  27 | 6/24/1987     | Mon, 08 Dec 2014 00:33:13 -0500 |
| Michael    | Jordan    |  51 | 2/17/1963     | Tue, 15 Nov 2014 00:33:13 -0500 |
| Lebron     | James     |  30 | 12/30/1984    | Fri, 02 Oct 2014 00:33:13 -0500 |
+------------+-----------+-----+---------------+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: `DELETE FROM archive WHERE MONTH(created_date) < MONTH(NOW)) AND YEAR(created_date)<=YEAR(NOW())`

Comment: @Hendry, that may not work so well on the first of the month, where it will kill of everything before today :-)

Comment: `:day` and `'days'`? Or is `:day` or `'days'` a typo? Edit: Yep, typo.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it was a typo, thanks. Corrected now.

Comment: Ok and you're welcome. Have you tried Gordon's answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM archive
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTR(created_date, 0, 25), '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%i:%S') <
      DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```

You can then remove the PHP code for calculating the date range and let MySQL handle it for you.

If you have control over the database structure, it will be much more efficient to store the date in a DATETIME field, rather than calling `STR_TO_DATE` on every database row.

Comment: I tried this as well but it is not deleting anything at all.

Comment: Followed your advice for changing to DATETIME field. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the `create_date` column is a string and not a date.  You can convert it to a date using `str_to_date()`:

```
delete from archive
    where str_to_date(substr(created_date, 6), '%d %b %Y') > :days;
```

Comment: from where did you get :day ?? i cant see a day column here..:o

Comment: @AvinashBabu thats what the OP set as a named placeholder in the prepared statement. and yes a typo indeed.

Comment: ...which is also a typo. @Ghost see my comment under OP's question. Edit: Yep, typo. Should be `:days`.

Comment: It still delete everything. Could this be the issue `$days = strtotime('1 month');`?

Comment: It should be %b instead of %M as your data is stored with the abbreviated month name.

Comment: I'm honestly amazed at how quickly your reputation has grown... but then again, almost 9,000 answers this year alone... Do you have a full-time job too?